# EdmMetadata error only in Azure Compute Emulator

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

I'm having trouble getting my application to run inside the Azure Compute Emulator. I'm using Entity Framework 6.0-pre2 and when my application runs, I get the following error:

> Invalid object name dbo.EdmMetadata

The database was created with Code First migrations. Using the same connection information, if it runs inside a regular console application or ASP.NET MVC 4 website, everything works correctly.

Relevant app.config sections:

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```

I've verified the DbContext is using the correct connection string with

```
string connection = db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
```

Is there a reason this is only happening when I start the task in the emulator (and when I deploy to Azure)?

Outer exception stack trace:

```
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Inner exception stack trace:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
```

Comment: It looks like setting Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(null) in the DbContext's static constructor fixes the problem, but why would this happen only under the Compute Emulator?

Comment: Show the stack trace. EdmMetadata was a table introduced in EF4.1 and then removed in EF4.3 (http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/01/13/ef-4-3-beta-1-what-happened-to-that-edmmetadata-table/) so I wonder how you happened to get it in EF6

Comment: Added the stack trace. There doesn't look to be any EF4 files around anywhere either.

Comment: Is by any chance when debugging?

Comment: Yep, happens when debugging.

Comment: Have you tried to continue? EF is checking whether EdmMetadata table exists in your db for upgrade/backwards compat scenarios. It then should handle the exception internally and therefore "continue" should just work (note that after you press "continue" most likely you will see a few more exceptions like this). I think you see this exception because you have "Break when exception is thrown" setting on (Debug=>Exceptions, Thrown column checked for Common Language Runtime Exceptions row). If you uncheck this setting VS should not break on exceptions that are being handled.

Comment: @Pawel If you add your comment as an answer I'll 1 up it.  I just had a coworker with this problem (nobody but him was seeing the exception).  We're not sure how it got checked...but...whatever.

Comment: @MikeH - I added the answer and included a link to a similar thread I responded to in the past.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because EF is checking whether EdmMetadata table exists in your db for upgrade/backwards compat scenarios. The exception is however handled by EF so you should not see it unless you have the "Break when exception is thrown" option turned on. With this option turned on any exception breaks the execution - even if it is handled and never reaches your code. You can just press continue to continue execution or disable breaking on first chance exceptions. 
Here is another thread with more details: 
[Invalid object name 'dbo.__MigrationHistory' using Database.Create; EF6.02 when connection string is passed in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877039/invalid-object-name-dbo-migrationhistory-using-database-create-ef6-02-when/20895515#20895515)